# Algorithms : when caching 5 datasources at different speeds, how to keep cross-datasource data up to date?

Tags: database, algorithm, database-design

I'm getting 5 different pieces of data on a regular basis from the internet. It's not quite price data, but it sort-of is, so I'm hoping using that as an example would help here.

Suppose I get prices for the all products from 5 stores. In each individual store's dataset there are various differences. Sometimes some products are missing. Sometimes one product is broken up in sub-products, or bundled, or ... Going from one "get" to the next, products may disappear, or appear.

Now I want to calculate and keep up-to-date a set of data that are summaries of all 5 datasets. So say, I want to keep track of the cheapest dvd player in all 5 datasets. How would I go about this ? Or the average price of all dvd players. Or ...

How would you go about architecting a database that does this sort of thing ?

Comment: Any specific problems? Sounds like you just need to write all data to a few tables and query it later. (It is not possible to usefully answer this right now.)

Comment: The problem is that I want to answer faster than it would take to calculate these values, but I'm constantly updating the underlying data. The example calculation I'm giving is much simpler than the actual one I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to calculate and keep up-to-date a set of data that are
>   summaries of all 5 datasets.

At one extreme, you just query the data when the user asks for it. Live with the consequences. (Queries can be slow, depending on a lot of factors. Materialized views might help.)

At the other extreme, you calculate everything, say, once a day. Live with the consequences. (Data might be 24 hours out of date.)

The basic database structure is the same regardless. If you calculate everything, say, once a day, you'll probably want one or more additional tables to store the calculated data.

---

Caching won't solve your problem, because

- you need to keep the result sets up to date,
- underlying data is constantly changing, and
- it takes too long to recalculate.

It seems your only options are faster queries, or living with the consequences of your situation. Faster queries begin with reading the execution plans. Every dbms from SQLite to Oracle includes a tool that tells you what the dbms thinks is the best way to go about returning the results you want.

You should approach this as a tuning problem. Since we don't know what your real problem is--we only see the simplified problem you wrote about--we can only give simplified suggestions.

Your dbms undoubtedly has documentation about most of these topics, if not all of them. Some of these things can be done at more than one level. DBMS support is uneven. For example, some support memory tuning at the query and session level, others only at the database or server level.

- Query tuning--look for sargable WHERE clauses, rewrite or eliminate correlated subqueries, set transaction isolation levels, run *different* queries (maybe using async methods like AJAX(, etc.
- Session tuning--per-session memory, session-level defaults for queries, etc.
- Table tuning--restructure, eliminate joins caused by surrogate keys, create indexes, consider "exotic" indexes, etc.
- Database tuning--move some tables and indexes to faster disks or SSDs, move transaction journals, log files, set different values for database-level parameters, change architecture (incorporate some data warehouse structures), etc.
- DBMS tuning--adjust buffer sizes and number, memory tuning, buffer allocation and tuning, etc., (very platform-dependent)
- Filesystem tuning--use a different filesystem altogether (research), automatic filesystem checks (can sometimes be disabled after 'n' days), stripe alignment, etc.
- Operating system tuning--test LVM performance, use different mount options, use different mkfs options, etc.
- Server tuning--faster hardware, better RAID card, different RAID level, switch some drives to SSD drives, update firmware, etc.

Comment: Same problem. I am somewhat simplifying the problem. The issue is that these calculations take too long, given the requests I want to support. So I really need to cache things.

Comment: Won't any cache be out of date as soon as the underlying data changes? And won't will be too costly (take too long) to update the cache on every data change? If so, a cache won't eliminate your problem. But faster calculations would.

Comment: @christopher: Triple the speed of your hardware, and you'll probably double the speed of your queries. See my expanded answer for more things to research.